# Why won't this angular equation ODE return the Legendre functions?

Tags: differential-equations

When I try to solve part of the angular equation for Schrodinger equation via the following code.

```
eqn2 = Sin[\[Theta]]*
    D[Sin[\[Theta]]*
      D[\[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]], \[Theta]], \[Theta]] + (l (l + 
         1) Sin^2[\[Theta]] - m^2)*\[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]];
DSolve[eqn2 == 0, \[CapitalTheta][\[Theta]], \[Theta]]
```

However, this generates the error "Inverse functions are being used. values may be lost for multivalued inverses" followed by "infinite expression encountered". I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: You should write `Sin[θ]^2` instead of `Sin^2[θ]`.

Comment: Then it works as expected, returning `{{Θ[θ] -> C[1] LegendreP[l, m, Cos[θ]] + C[2] LegendreQ[l, m, Cos[θ]]}}`

Comment: Thank you so much! @Domen

Answer (score 1):

After multiplication by sin^2 th, the angular part of the Schrödinger equation is

```
   Seqn[f_, th_] := - Sin[th]*D[Sin[th]* f'[th], th] + m^2 f[th] == 
   l (l + 1) Sin[th]^2 f[th]  ;

Seqn[Theta, th]

m^2 Theta[th] - Sin[th] (Cos[th] Derivative[1][Theta][th] + 
Sin[th] (Theta^\[Prime]\[Prime])[th]) == l (1 + l) Sin[th]^2 Theta[th]

DSolve[Seqn[Theta, th], Theta[th], th] // Simplify // PowerExpand

{{Theta[th] -> C[1] LegendreP[l, m, Cos[th]] + C[2] LegendreQ[l, m, Cos[th]]}}
```